# How to determine whether a file is part of base OS installation?

Tags: macos, sip

Is it possible to tell whether a file on my Mac (M1 with OS 12.1) was part of the original OS installation, rather than something I installed myself?

I thought I could just [see whether the files](https://www.alansiu.net/2020/09/09/terminal-command-to-tell-if-a-macos-directory-is-sip-protected/) were protected by [System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899) (assuming I hadn't turned this off). But some protected files were installed by me on an older Mac without SIP, then migrated using Migration Assistant.

Is the only option to install MacOS on another disk and see what it installs?

Comment: Does "original/base OS installation" include everything up to first user login? Or just what is on the read-only signed system volume?

Comment: One method is to tag color all the files after a fresh install before installing 3rd party stuff.

Comment: @Gilby It looks like the signed system volume [includes](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210650) files that were migrated from previous systems, including user-installed files. I guess I'm looking for everything that would be on a new machine before the first user login.

Comment: Which specific files are you looking at here?

Comment: PS: It seems unlikely that Migration Assistant can break and reseal SSV by itself

Comment: @nohillside Maybe I was mistaken about that. In that case, would the answer to my question be: anything not on the System volume was user-installed? And is there a way to tell what's not on the System volume?